# ¿Cómo podría sumar dos filas de una misma tabla y sacar el peso de cada IDcliente que se repite?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

necesito sacar el peso de cada cliente basado en los mantenimientos actuales. Ahora saco el peso de cada mantenimiento, pero necesito agrupar los mantenimientos y sumarlos para sacar la cifra global por cliente, ya que un cliente puede tener varios mantenimientos.

```
   SELECT
       nombre, IDempresa, ((precio/periodopago)*12)  as precio,
      CONCAT(
        ROUND(
          ( ((precio/periodopago)*12) / F2.totalPrecio * 100 ),
          2 
        ), '%'
      ) AS porcentaje
    FROM
      facturas_mantenimiento,empresas
    CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT SUM( ((precio/periodopago)*12) ) as totalPrecio FROM facturas_mantenimiento) F2 WHERE empresas.ID = IDempresa AND  YEAR(fechacobro)=".date("Y")." AND m_activo='si' and codigo_cuenta!='705000001' 
    ORDER BY `porcentaje`  DESC
```

ahora me sale así:

| IDempresa | Precio |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 15 |
| 3 | 40 |

y lo que deseo que salga en la consulta resultante sería esto

| IDempresa | Total | Peso |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 60 | XX % |
| 4 | 10 | XX % |
| 5 | 15 | XX % |

Es decir, primero tendría que SUMAR todos los importes de la misma tabla donde se repita el IDempresa. Una vez tenga todos los totales, debo calcular entre todo el % de peso que le corresponde a cada cliente.

Comment: Pon un `GROUP BY laColumnaIDDelCliente`  y en el `SELECT` coloca un  `SUM(laColumnaQueQuieresSumar)` para sumar los valores que te interesa.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask], y [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Con un ejemplo gráfico se te entendería mejor

Comment: Pones como te sale ahora y como debería salirte, pero seria bueno que añadieras en un gráfico, como esta la información originalmente, para uno ver mejor y poder comparar, la información original con el resultado que deseas

Comment: @A.Cedano ya he puesto lo que me has comentado y me ha funcionado PERO no me calcula el peso global. Si me hace la suma pero el peso no lo aplica bien.

Comment: @Javifer2  agregado ejemplo gráfico en tablas

Comment: @Japv agregado ejemplo. A ver si ahora me he explicado mejor. Perdón pero es mi primera vez y no sabía bien cómo ponerlo.

Answer (score 1):

CONSEGUIDO !! La respuesta correcta sería esta

```
SELECT
   nombre, IDempresa, SUM(((precio/periodopago)*12))  as precio,
  CONCAT(
    ROUND(
      SUM(( ((precio/periodopago)*12) / F2.totalPrecio * 100 )),
      2 
    ), '%'
  ) AS porcentaje
FROM
  facturas_mantenimiento,empresas
CROSS JOIN
  ( SELECT SUM( ((precio/periodopago)*12) ) as totalPrecio FROM facturas_mantenimiento ) F2 WHERE empresas.ID = IDempresa AND  YEAR(fechacobro)=".date("Y")." AND m_activo='si' and codigo_cuenta!='705000001' GROUP BY IDempresa
ORDER BY `porcentaje`  DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Ampliando la información que te comenta A.Cedano, sobre el funcionamiento de las agrupaciones de SQL.

Supongamos que tenemos una tabla con las columnas Cliente y Precio:

Tabla Cliente

| cliente | precio |
| --- | --- |
| cliente1 | 14 |
| cliente1 | 16 |
| cliente2 | 15 |

La siguiente consulta:
SELECT cliente, SUM(precio)
FROM pedidos
GROUP BY cliente

Tendría este resultado:

| cliente | precio |
| --- | --- |
| cliente1 | 30 |
| cliente2 | 15 |

Como ves la sentencia group le dice a SQL que "junte" las filas por el campo o campos que le indicas y luego la función "SUM" le indica como debe fusionar las filas que tienen el mismo valor en el campo sobre el que se agrupa. Con SUM suma el valor, con count cuenta las filas, ...

Te dejo el siguiente enlace para que veas un ejemplo más completo de como funciona GroupBy: [Ejemplo GroupBy y SUM](http://m.sql.11sql.com/sql-funcion-group-by.htm)

Un saludo!

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/272186)

Comment: @Israel-ICM añadida información adicional a la respuesta. Gracias por tus comentarios.